# How to block emails from unverified addresses in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I commonly receive spam emails trying to impersonate my work domain and the email will say something like `<someuser@myworkdomain.com> via <otherdomain.com>` is there a way to block all emails like this? Blocking the `<otherdomain.com>` doesn't seem to work since it's trying to appear as `<myworkdomain.com>`.

I feel like this is something my company should be filtering, but I can't do anything about that personally, so is there a way for me to block these sorts of emails? Clearly Outlook has a way of detecting these emails otherwise they wouldn't display the warning below.

> We could not verify the idnetity of the sender. Click here to learn more.
> The actual sender of this message is different than the normal sender. Click here to learn more.

Comment: Unless you are an Administrator, and have access to the appropriate configuration page, you won’t be able to do what you want.

Comment: Hmm that's what I was afraid of. So this is a server-level configuration only then? I don't see why Outlook doesn't have something for this since it clearly can detect it otherwise it wouldn't warn me about it.

Comment: What you describe is indeed at the server level.  What you describe is not client-side filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Do these spam messages have anything in common?
Is there any similarity within the sender's information displayed in the message header? If so, maybe you could try to create an Outlook rule to automatically move emails with certain information in the message header to the deleted folder.

[image]
[image]

Comment: They all have the "via <otherdomain.com>" in them, but I don't see a rule for that. Doing a rule on their address only applies to the fake domain and not the actual domain it's from, hence the question.

Comment: Please try create Outlook rule like screenshots above and see if it could helps.